# Dropdown button not displaying links

Tags: html, css

Was following a tutorial on how to create a hoverable drop-down button with HTML/CSS. The button displays on the page when I load but does not display the links when I hover over it. I thought it may have been the browser but it does the same thing in Firefox and google chrome. I changed the code around when I tried it initially, then typed the code verbatim as the tutorial but had the same issue. Tried to post screenshot of page but site would not allow me yet.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: brown;
}

.crumbs-btn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.crumbs {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-crumbs {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-crumbs a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-crumbs a: hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.crumbs: hover .dropdown-crumbs {
  display: block;
}

.crumbs: hover .crumbs-btn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Memoir of the mind</title>
  <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Fish for Waves</h1>
    <!--<p>this will refresh after ten seconds</p> -->

    <p\><b>The website dedicated to providing daily gems of wisdom
     to help nourish your mind and spirit.</b></p>

      <img src="pictures\Thinking-Man.jpg" alt="Thinking-Man" width="200" height="300">
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="proverbs or phrases">
    <h2>Daily Crumbs</h2>
    <h4>February 28, 2022</h4>
    <p>"Wisdom stems from the tree of experience and the branch of patience"</p>
    <p>-<i>Buddy Nawlidge</i></p>
  </div>

  <div class="crumbs">
    <button class="crumbs-btn">Previous Crumbs</button>
    <div class="dropdown-crumbs">
      <a href="http:www.google.com">Mar 9th, 2022</a>
      <a href="http:www.google.com">Mar 10th, 2022</a>
      <a href="http:www.google.com">Mar 11th, 2022</a>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide your CSS from HTML. Create a CSS file, I named mine app.css

This is the snippet:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: brown;
}

.crumbs-btn {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.crumbs {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-crumbs {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-crumbs a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-crumbsa:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.crumbs:hover .dropdown-crumbs {
  visibility: visible;
}

.crumbs:hover .crumbs-btn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Memoir of the mind</title>
  <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Fish for Waves</h1>
    <!--<p>this will refresh after ten seconds</p> -->

    <p><b>The website dedicated to providing daily gems of wisdom
     to help nourish your mind and spirit.</b></p>

    <img src="pictures\Thinking-Man.jpg" alt="Thinking-Man" width="200" height="300">
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="proverbs or phrases">
    <h2>Daily Crumbs</h2>
    <h4>February 28, 2022</h4>
    <p>"Wisdom stems from the tree of experience and the branch of patience"</p>
    <p>-<i>Buddy Nawlidge</i></p>
  </div>

  <div class="crumbs">
    <button class="crumbs-btn">Previous Crumbs</button>
    <div class="dropdown-crumbs">
      <a href="http:www.google.com">Mar 9th, 2022</a>
      <a href="http:www.google.com">Mar 10th, 2022</a>
      <a href="http:www.google.com">Mar 11th, 2022</a>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

I used visibility hidden and visible but it also works with your way too. There are many solutions to do the same thing. There is nothing wrong with your code but I think you should divide your HTML from the CSS (external) so that the hover works better.